# TLS with selfsigned certificate

Tags: ssl, go

I'm trying to establish a TLS connection with the use of a self signed server certificate.

I generated the certificate with this example code: http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

My relevant client code looks like that:

```golang
// server cert is self signed -> server_cert == ca_cert
CA_Pool := x509.NewCertPool()
severCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./cert.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Could not load server certificate!")
}
CA_Pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(severCert)

config := tls.Config{RootCAs: CA_Pool}

conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8000", &config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("client: dial: %s", err)
}
```

And the relevant server code like that:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./cert.pem", "./key.pem")
config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8000", &config)

for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("server: accept: %s", err)
        break
    }
    log.Printf("server: accepted from %s", conn.RemoteAddr())
    go handleConnection(conn)
}
```

Because the server certificate is self signed is use the same certificate for the server and the clients CA_Pool however this does not seem to work since i always get this error:

```
client: dial: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority 
(possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate
cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying to verify 
candidate authority certificate "serial:0")
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It finally worked with the go built in x509.CreateCertificate, 
the problem was that **I did not set the IsCA:true flag**,
**I only set the x509.KeyUsageCertSign** which made creating the self signed certificate work, but crashed while verifying the cert chain.

Comment: Thank you Zap, this helped point me in the direction of how to solve this, I posted a short self contained example of an ansible automated solution + explanation, as an answer to another related question, I don't want to duplicate my answer so I'm linking to the other related Q&A.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288371/docker-private-registry-using-selfsigned-certificates/59154493#59154493

Comment: It looks like `BasicConstraintsValid: true` may also be needed.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you need a [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) certificate in the server-side config, and this CA must have signed the server's certificate.

I have written some Go code that will [generate](http://kylelemons.net/browse/gitweb.cgi/go/ccert.git/blob/HEAD:/ca/ca.go#l83) a CA certificate, but it hasn't been reviewed by anyone and is mostly a toy for playing around with client certs.  The safest bet is probably to use [`openssl ca`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/) to generate and sign the certificate.  The basic steps will be:

1. Generate a CA Certificate
2. Generate a Server key
3. Sign the Server key with the CA certificate
4. Add the CA Certificate to the client's [`tls.Config`](http://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Config) `RootCAs`
5. Set up the server's `tls.Config` with the Server key and signed certificate.

Answer (score 4):

Kyle, is correct.  This tool will do what you want and it simplifies the entire process:

https://github.com/deckarep/EasyCert/releases (only OSX is supported since it uses the openssl tool internally)

and the source:

https://github.com/deckarep/EasyCert

Basically with this tool it will generate a bundle of files but you will need the three that it outputs when it's done.

1. a CA root cer file
2. a Server cer file
3. a Server key file

Comment: OK, I used EasyCert but now I get a: "client: dial: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs" what are IS SANs

Comment: I'm going to out on a limb here and say you might be hitting a bug in Go: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4658  Perhaps try upgrading your Go version if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when using mysql client in Go:

```
Failed to connect to database:  x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.111.202.229 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

and setting `InsecureSkipVerify` to `true` (to skip verification of certificate) resolved it for me:

https://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Config

The following code worked for me:

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
 "crypto/tls"
 "crypto/x509"
 "io/ioutil"
 "log"
)

func main() {
    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ccp-root-ca.crt")
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append root CA cert at /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ccp-root-ca.crt.")
    }
    mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: rootCertPool,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "ccp-user:I6qnD6zNDmqdDLXYg3HqVAk2P@tcp(10.111.202.229:3306)/ccp?tls=custom")
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the certificate I appended was not encoded correctly in pem format. 
If using keytools, ensure to append -rfc while exporting the certificate from keystore, pem encoded could be opened in a text editor to display:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDiDCCAnCgAwIBAgIEHKSkvDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBi...`

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the InsecureSkipVerify flag, refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/c9zEiH6ixyw.

The related code of this post (incase the page is offline):

```
smtpbox := "mail.foo.com:25"
c, err := smtp.Dial(smtpbox)

host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(smtpbox)
tlc := &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ServerName:         host,
}
if err = c.StartTLS(tlc); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err)
    os.Exit(1)
} 
// carry on with rest of smtp transaction 
// c.Auth, c.Mail, c.Rcpt, c.Data, etc
```

Comment: You should be verifying SSL certificates rather than just accepting any SSL certificate.

Comment: This is an important workaround for testing, and really helped me to know about. Thank you!

Comment: InsecureSkipVerify means "safety = off". That subjects you to MITM attacks. That is safe only for development!

Comment: Good option for dev testing.