# Can not connect from golang to docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, go, docker

I spin up the docker container for postgres

`docker run -i -t -v=":/var/lib/postgresql" -p 5432:5432 my_image/postgresql:9.3`

And verify that it is reachable from host using

`psql -h my_docker_ip -p 5432 -U pguser -W pgdb // passowrd: pguser`

Now I want to connect to the container `postgres` using `go` in my host machine.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=pguser password='pguser' host=192.168.99.100 port=5432 sslmode=verify-full")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM test")
    fmt.Println(rows)

}
```

While there were no error on initializing the db instance reference, the test query itself print out

```
<nil>
```

This should not happen because I created table `test` and multiple rows in table `test` prior to running the go code.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If it were not able to `Open` it should have failed and error returned on `Open`,

Comment: ah, the error I got is during the query, `x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.100 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

Comment: sql.Open doesn't check if there's a valid connection, use [sql.Ping](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Ping)

Comment: just try setting `disable` sslmode for development phase

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when using mysql client in golang:

```
Failed to connect to database:  x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.111.202.229 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54636760/8645590 worked for me.